# How can I create multiple fingerprint scan and register in db?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I want to create an app to register a new fingerprint and add more fingerprint and authenticate in same app, but i am able to authenticate only one with the hardware supported fingerprint only.

So my requirement is:

1. Register fingerprint as an image scanner through app and send them to db or server.
2. Authenticate scanned fingerprint in same app through db or server where fingerprint was saved.

with the help of [google sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog) i can scan system's scanned fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid but you can't. Android-native fingerprint authentication is only for authenticating the user to the device. 
You cannot register or access fingerprint data from your app.
In your app, you can only authenticate against the registered fingerprints on the device. Probably using any 3rd party scanner might solve your problem but not with Android-native fingerprint api.